# Program that creates random numbers from 1 to n, without repeating, and stores them in array of size n

Tags: c#, arrays, random

Well, I've been coding this program that has the objective to create random numbers, and then store them in an array (`linhas[n]`), but I don't want them to repeat.
I started by doing a for loop `(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` and inside it I wrote that a variable `a` (`int a`) was equal to a random number generated from the random function (r). Then I compared if `a` already existed in the array, using `bool b = Array.Exists(linhas, elements => elements == a);`, then wrote that if `b` was true it would decrease the `i` value by one, to repeat the same `i` loop, doing `linhas[i] = a` if `b` was false. Then it would write the elements of the array.
The problem that I'm getting is that when I open the program and write the value of `n` the program just doesn't do nothing, just a black screen. I already checked and if I put the value of `n = 1`, the program generates just one number, number 1. But if I put `n = 2` it just stops.
If anyone understood what I said here and could help me, please just throw some tips!

The code here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n;
    Console.Write("Escreva o número de linhas a aparecer: ");
    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] linhas = new int[n];
    var r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        int a = r.Next(1, n);
        bool b = Array.Exists(linhas, elements => elements == a);
        if (b == true)
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            linhas[i] = a;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linhas[i]);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: This is often done with the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: There are literally hundreds of posts already here with this goal

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That doesn't generate random integers in a range, and it doesn't prevent duplicate random values.

Comment: You would be far better off to use `Array.IndexOf` or creating a `HashSet<int>` and testing with `HashSet<T>.Contains()` then converting it to an `int[]` once it is filled.

Comment: Also, changing the index variable of a `for` loop outside the `for` statement is a poor practice - don't use a `for` loop in that case, or use an inner loop to find an acceptable random value.

Comment: If you don't want repeats then you don't want random numbers, you want [1, 2, 3, 4, ... n] shuffled into a random order.  As @Andrew Morton says, use the Fisher-Yates shuffle to give you a good random shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random range is not valid. Your fault is r.Next(1, n) mean is [1;n). I fixed that r.Next(1, n+1).
Hope this helps. Bye!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class MyClass
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n;
        Console.Write("Escreva o número de linhas a aparecer: ");
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] linhas = new int[n];
        var r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n;)
        {
            int a = r.Next(1, n + 1);
            #region Using LINQ
            //if (linhas.Contains(a))
            //{
            //    continue;
            //}
            #endregion
            #region Using Array Exists
            bool b = Array.Exists(linhas, elements => elements == a);
            if (b == true)
            {
                continue;
            }
            #endregion
            else
            {
                linhas[i] = a;
                i++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(linhas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks turaltahmazli, now the program does what I wanted.